# Paint Swing JButton as disabled

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, paintcomponent

I want to display a normal JButton as disabled, without setting it to setEnabled(false)!

I just want to show that this button is not enabled, but if the user pushs the button it should call the actionlistener as normal.

So what I did is:

```
import java.awt.Graphics;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class SwingTests {

    private static void createWindow() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();

        MyButton button = new MyButton("Press");
        button.setEnabled(false);

        panel.add(button);
        frame.add(panel);
        frame.setSize(200, 200);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                createWindow();
            }
        });
    }
}

class MyButton extends JButton {
    private boolean enabled = false;

    public MyButton(String text) {
        super(text);
        super.setEnabled(true);
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintBorder(Graphics g) {
        if (isEnabled())
            super.paintBorder(g);
        else
            ; // paint disabled button
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        if (isEnabled())
            super.paintComponent(g);
        else
            ; // paint disabled button
    }

    @Override
    public void setEnabled(boolean b) {
        enabled = b;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return enabled;
    }
}
```

I "just" need to know what to write in paintComponent(g) and paintBorder(g).

Comment: *"I just want to show that this button is not enabled, but if the user pushs the button it should call the actionlistener as normal."*  Sound like yet another 'unusable GUI' in the making.  What is the use-case where that actually makes *sense?*

Comment: *"button is not enabled, but if the user pushes the button it should call the actionlistener as normal"* Is the button suppose to be an easter egg? I don't know what are you trying to achieve.

Comment: I know this is against propper GUI design an with "Sound like yet another 'unusable GUI' in the making" you are partially right! But i want this because if it is disabled and a user pushs the button i display an alarm why this button is disabled!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> if it is disabled and a user pushs the button i display an alarm why this button is disabled!

Add a MouseListener to the button when it is disabled. Then you can handle the mouseClicked() event to display your "alarm".

Answer (score 1):

> if it is disabled and a user pushs the button i display an alarm why this button is disabled!

If it looks disabled I am probably not going to push it in the first place.  You could achieve this type of effect using tool tips.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JToggleButton;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class TestGUI {
    public TestGUI() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        final JButton button = new JButton("Press Me");
        final JToggleButton enable = new JToggleButton("Enable / Disable");
        enable.setSelected(true);
        button.setToolTipText("Enabled");
        enable.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                if (enable.isSelected()) {
                    button.setEnabled(true);
                    button.setToolTipText("Enabled");
                } else {
                    button.setEnabled(false);
                    button.setToolTipText("Not Enabled");
                }

            }

        });
        frame.add(button, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.add(enable, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new TestGUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```